# Sorting Elements of a List

Tags: r

I have a list

```
str(overlaps)
List of 7
 $ a5: chr [1:6] "calc_a1c" "predmdx_flag" "bmi" "systolic" ...
 $ a2: chr [1:2] "age" "yr"
 $ a4: chr(0) 
 $ a6: chr(0) 
 $ a1: chr [1:2] "trig_3cat" "glipizide_flag"
 $ a3: chr [1:2] "email_flag" "statins_flag"
 $ a7: chr [1:4] "trig_3cat.>=200" "antihtn_flag" "black_flag" "gender.M"
```

And I want to reorder the list such that the resulting list is one where the elements are in numerical order. ie a1, a2, a3, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some random data:

```
set.seed(42)
overlaps <- replicate(5, runif(3), simplify=FALSE)
names(overlaps) <- paste0("a", sample(5))
str(overlaps)
# List of 5
#  $ a5: num [1:3] 0.915 0.937 0.286
#  $ a4: num [1:3] 0.83 0.642 0.519
#  $ a1: num [1:3] 0.737 0.135 0.657
#  $ a3: num [1:3] 0.705 0.458 0.719
#  $ a2: num [1:3] 0.935 0.255 0.462
```

The sort:

```
str(overlaps[ sort(names(overlaps)) ])
# List of 5
#  $ a1: num [1:3] 0.737 0.135 0.657
#  $ a2: num [1:3] 0.935 0.255 0.462
#  $ a3: num [1:3] 0.705 0.458 0.719
#  $ a4: num [1:3] 0.83 0.642 0.519
#  $ a5: num [1:3] 0.915 0.937 0.286
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to r2evans' answer, which is excellent. I used his example dataset.

```
str(overlaps[order(names(overlaps))])

#List of 5
# $ a1: num [1:3] 0.737 0.135 0.657
# $ a2: num [1:3] 0.935 0.255 0.462
# $ a3: num [1:3] 0.705 0.458 0.719
# $ a4: num [1:3] 0.83 0.642 0.519
# $ a5: num [1:3] 0.915 0.937 0.286
```